# Java - Return information from a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, return

So what I want to do is return:

Input is `createMixedString(Hello,there,3)`

and I want to output `HellothereHellothereHellothere`

My problem is when it runs it just returns `Hellothere` as if the program didn't see the reassigning i did inside the for loop.

```
public static String createMixedString(String s1, String s2, int n) {
    String result = s1+s2;

    for (int i=0;i>=n;i++) {
        result = result+s1+s2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Check the condition, I think you put the ">" the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Your for condition is wrong, it should be **i < n** as in:

```
public static String createMixedString(String s1, String s2, int n) {
    String result = s1+s2;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        result = result+s1+s2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
  public static String createMixedString(String s1, String s2, int n) {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          s.append(s1);
          s.append(s2);
      }
      return s.toString();
  }
```

Notice that the check in the condition checks to see if `i` is still less than `n`, as opposed to check while `i >= n`, which doesn't make sense. Also, using a `StringBuilder` will be much more efficient if you're concatenating Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use StringUtils.repeat it will do the same thing for you so you could do the following:

```
public static String createMixedString(String s1, String s2, int n) {
    String result = s1 + s2;
    return StringUtils.repeat(result, n);
}
```

This should work the way you want it

Answer (score 0):

`0 >= 3` condition never satisfies. It should `i < n`. Because i starts at 0, it should be `<` not <=

```
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {    
     result = result+s1+s2;  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the loop condition `i>=n` should be `i<=n`.

Answer (score 0):

your loop end condition is the issue, change it to i < n